# Vuetify : filter v-data-table items when a button clicked

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have a table like this ,
[image]
I want when I clicked on **filter Button** alll items that both **male** and **valid** are **true** to be filtered .

```js
users = [
    { name: 'ali', male: true, valid: true },
    { name: 'kevin', male: true, valid: false },
    { name: 'meri', male: false, valid: false }
  ]
  get headerst() {
    return [
      {
        text: 'user',
        align: 'start',

        value: 'name'
      },
      {
        text: 'male',
        value: 'male'
      },
      {
        text: 'valid',
        value: 'valid'
      }
    ]
  }
  filterOnlyCapsText(value, search, item) {
    return (
      value != null &&  typeof value === 'boolean' && value===true
    )
  }
  filter(){
  // i dont know
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<v-btn @click="filter">filter</v-btn>
    <v-data-table
     
      :headers="headerst"
      :items="users"
      item-key="name"
      class="elevation-1"
      :custom-filter="filterOnlyCapsText"
    >
 
 
    </v-data-table>
```

I have written code but it doesn't work .

How can fix this ??

this text is nothing just  to avoid stack error
this text is nothing just  to avoid stack error
this text is nothing just  to avoid stack error
this text is nothing just  to avoid stack error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that, you will need to update your filter method to return this:

```js
return value != null &&
        search != null &&
        typeof value === 'string' &&
        value.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1 && 
        item.male === true && 
        item.valid === true;
```

This means that from `item` you can read `male` and `valid` properties to match. Also this line `value.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1` will make sure that searched text matches value.

Also, if you want to have a button that you can click and filter only those that are male and valid, then you need to create a computed property called `filteredUsers`, that will look like this:

```js
filteredUsers(){
      if(this.onlyValidAndMale){
        return this.users.filter(user => user.male == true && user.valid == true)
      }
      
      return this.users;
    },
```

Notice that there is this `onlyValidAndMale` property there, that you need to define in `data()`.

When you have that, you should be using that `filteredUsers` as a `:items` in your table.

You should create one button that would be switching this property `onlyValidAndMale` to true and false when clicked, and it can look like this:

```html
 <v-btn @click="onlyValidAndMale = !onlyValidAndMale">Click here to filter only those that are male and valid.</v-btn>
```

Complete working example is here:

https://codepen.io/vokekaw624/pen/GROgJVP

HTML FILE:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="filteredUsers"
        item-key="name"
        class="elevation-1"
        :search="search"
        :custom-filter="filterOnlyMaleAndValid"
      >
        <template v-slot:top>
          <v-text-field
            v-model="search"
            label="Search (Will match only male = true and valid = true)"
            class="mx-4"
          ></v-text-field>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </div>
        <v-btn @click="onlyValidAndMale = !onlyValidAndMale">Click here to filter only those that are male and valid.</v-btn>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS FILE:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      search: '',
      onlyValidAndMale: false,
      users: [
    { name: 'ali', male: true, valid: true },
    { name: 'muhamed', male: true, valid: true },
    { name: 'sami', male: true, valid: true },
    { name: 'kevin', male: true, valid: false },
    { name: 'meri', male: false, valid: false }
  ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredUsers(){
      if(this.onlyValidAndMale){
        return this.users.filter(user => user.male == true && user.valid == true)
      }
      
      return this.users;
    },
    headers () {
      return [
      {
        text: 'user',
        align: 'start',

        value: 'name'
      },
      {
        text: 'male',
        value: 'male'
      },
      {
        text: 'valid',
        value: 'valid'
      }
    ]
    },
  },
  methods: {
    filterOnlyMaleAndValid (value, search, item) {
      return value != null &&
        search != null &&
        typeof value === 'string' &&
        value.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1 && 
        item.male === true && 
        item.valid === true;
    },
  },
})
```

Notice that I updated the name of the filter method to better match what it does, but it works just as expected.

Comment: have you tested it ?

Comment: it doesnt worked for me !

Comment: Yes, I tested it and it works - here is the codepen of a working example: https://codepen.io/vokekaw624/pen/GROgJVP?editors=101 - I also updated the answer.

Comment: it works only when you **write** something in search field , i want when i **click** on a **button** it filter all items that **valid** and **male** is **true** , do you think it is **possible** ??

Comment: It is definitely possible, but you didn't say that in your initial question. Please update the question with more details, and I'll provide an answer based on updated question. Thank you!

Comment: I edited question

Comment: @kevin I updated the answer and the codepen solution. I hope that is what you needed.

Comment: it works BUT not using v-data-table custome filter , do you think it can not done with that ?

Comment: It can be done that way too, but it would complicate things further and is not the approach I would recommend. This one is much cleaner and simpler. Leave `v-data-table` filter for what it is 
intended to be.